# Do Views and View-models have to be in the same location

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm at the point of needing to restructure my Aurelia app to make it more extensible. I have several views and view-models in my `src/`folder.

I want to know if it's possible to separate the two like:

```
src/views/
src/view-models/
```

then within each of those two directories, further separate like:

```
src/views/admin/admin.html
src/view-models/admin/admin.js

src/views/user/user.html
src/view-models/user/user.js
```

Comment: @Iasec0203 - In a long run its not advisable to separate view and view-models the you are using right now. You should keep it both view and view-model together as a module

Answer (score 2):

> Do Views and View-models have to be in the same location?

Not necessarily. It's more like a convention/recommendation than a constraint. Documentation has some details on how to [customize conventions](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/app-configuration-and-startup/9).

**Example main.js**

This overrides everything, but you have the freedom to override view paths partially.

E.g. `if (moduleId.indexOf('specific-module-name') !== -1) ...`

```js
export function configure(aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration();

  // locator override
  ViewLocator.prototype.convertOriginToViewUrl = (origin) => {
    let moduleId = origin.moduleId,
              id = (moduleId.endsWith('.js') || moduleId.endsWith('.ts')) ? moduleId.substring(0, moduleId.length - 3) : moduleId,
         viewPath = id.replace('view-models/', 'views/') + '.html';

    return viewPath;
  };

  aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible generate folder inside view.
this can be done by using "area" in mvc

Step1:Right click on project
Step 2: click on new
Step 3 : first select "Area"[image]

Comment: I don't even know what program that is and what you are trying to show. I'm not using an IDE by the way. I use atom text editor

Comment: He is referring to ASP.NET mvc

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by default Aurelia forces you to use the same name for view and View-model. but you can also use the compose element to choose the model and datamodel from different folders

E.g.

```js
<compose view-model="./src/view-model/some-view" model.bind="./src/model/some-view" />
```